# How to print (to a printer) full DOM of a react page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, printing

I'm trying to allow a user to print a page of React (ideally just using `window.print()`). However, when I try to print it only shows the active portion of the page (what can be seen in the browser) and not the full page (everything including what's below the fold). I've seen that this is a problem with React apps in general and not just my app. What's the best way to print everything on the page?

Comment: Do you have screenshots of this? Sounds rather like a CSS issue.